# Why does facebook’s graph API return a permissions error when I try to get the “owner” of any facebook event that I am personally invited to?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook's graph api. The access token I am using is the User's access token, (my personal access token). I am invited to these events personally. These events are public.

When I type `/{eventid}/?fields=owner`, I get

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) Permissions error",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "DcJaHySwF7S"
  }
}
```

`When I do /{eventid}/?fields=cover` or most other fields it works just fine.

I am using the online graph tool v3.3 and tried it on v3.2 as well.
I have also tried this on curl on my personal terminal.

Below is the oath permissions I have set using the Graph API explorer.

[Permission's Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvgOO.png)

Comment: is this about a user event or a page event? did you try with both?

Comment: Thanks for asking, this permissions error occurs both when people (users) host events and when pages host events. In the case of people, these are people I am friends with. And in the case with pages, they are pages that I have liked.

Comment: Just because someone is friends with you, does not automatically give you API access to their profile - they would need to log in to your app, and explicitly grant it permission. And for pages you have no admin access to, your app would need to apply for [Page Public Content Access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS) first, otherwise no API access to those either.

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot even get the list of Page Events right now (even if you own the Page), I assume it´s not possible: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/events/

> This is a restricted edge. You cannot request access at this time.